# I exported xray test issues with Export as XML in Jira search, but the line returns aren't there

Tags: jira, jira-xray

I exported many Xray test issues with the Export as XML feature in the Jira search, but the line returns aren't there.

If you check for e.g., the < Action > tag or the < Expected result > tag you found there the same text you have in Jira, but all the line returns you have are converted to space in the exported XML

Comment: 1. Are you using Xray on Jira server or Xray on Jira cloud? 2) What is exactly your question and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not cloud. I want to export the Xray tests with the export in XML function with keeping all my line returns in my tests. I am wondering if it possible.

Answer (score 0):

In Xray for Jira datacenter, that's currently how the XML mapping is done; these fields appear as stripped CDATA, with wiki notation.
XML export is a native Jira feature; it takes advantage of the fact that there is a custom field that has information about the steps, and that's why it actually appears on the XML export.
This behaviour is non-configurable.
If you wish, you may [reach out Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) and ask the team to analyse this and see if an improvement is possible or not.
I'm unsure about why you need a XML export but if you want a machine friendly output, the best option would be to use Xray REST API and implement a script to obtain that information in the format that you aim.

Comment: I need the XML to export the Xray tests. The XML file is convertible to CSV using EXCEL. Using the API, I can export them but only with JSON format. Notice that before I tried the XML export I tried the export in CSV, and the export in XLS from the functions available in the JIRA search but all are giving me the manual test steps column in JSON format. For me the XML was best for this export since I can specify the columns I need in the URL, and I can export multiple Xray test issues at the same. Unfortunately, there is the problem of line returns that are all removed from my tests.